# ddply aggregated column names

Tags: r, plyr

I am using ddply to aggregate my data but haven't found an elegant way to assign column names to the output data frame.

At the moment I am doing this:

```
agg_data <- ddply(raw_data, .(id, date, classification), nrow)
names(agg_data)[4] <- "no_entries"
```

and this

```
agg_data <- ddply(agg_data, .(classification, date), colwise(mean, .(no_entries)) )
names(agg_data)[3] <- "avg_no_entries"
```

Is there a better, more elegant way to do this?

Comment: You might also want to look at `count`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `summarise`:

```
agg_data <- ddply(raw_data, .(id, date, classification), summarise, "no_entries" = nrow(piece))
```

or you can use `length(<column_name>)` if `nrow(piece)` doesn't work. For instance, here's an example that should be runnable by anyone:

```
ddply(baseball, .(year), summarise, newColumn = nrow(piece))
```

or

```
ddply(baseball, .(year), summarise, newColumn = length(year))
```

**EDIT**

Or as Joshua comments, the all caps version, `NROW` does the checking for you.

Comment: `NROW` does the necessary checking for you.

Comment: that works nicely; I wasn't aware of the `piece` variable. Do you have any idea how it works when I already use the colwise function? I added a second example to the question above.

Comment: @behas - not sure exactly what you mean; your 2nd example could be accomplished with `..., summarise, mean(no_entries))`. Or were you asking about the `piece` variable?

Answer (score 9):

The generic form I use a lot is:

```
 ddply(raw_data, .(id, date, classification), function(x) data.frame( no_entries=nrow(x) )
```

I use anonymous functions in my `ddply` statements almost all the time so the above idiom meshes well with anonymous functions. This is not the most concise way to express a function like `nrow()` but with functions where I pass multiple arguments, I like it a lot.